# Selecting text from a JLabel?

Tags: java, swing

Is it possible to enable the selection of text from a JLabel?  If not, what's the best alternative control to use, and how can it be configured to appear like a JLabel?

Answer (score 36):

A JTextField doesn't allow html-formatted text like a JLabel. If you want selectable html text you could alternatively try a JTextPane set to html formatting:

```
JTextPane f = new JTextPane();
f.setContentType("text/html"); // let the text pane know this is what you want
f.setText("<html>Hello World</html>"); // showing off
f.setEditable(false); // as before
f.setBackground(null); // this is the same as a JLabel
f.setBorder(null); // remove the border
```

Comment: This post has a useful suggestion to get the font to match what would normally be shown on a JLabel: https://explodingpixels.wordpress.com/2008/10/28/make-jeditorpane-use-the-system-font/

Comment: We can also use `setOpaque(false);` instead of `setBackground(null);`

Comment: This is also great because once you get used to it, it allows you to add additional styles to the text. Only thing I dislike is that it no longer uses Swing normal font.

Answer (score 14):

You can use a JTextField without enabling the editing

```
JTextField f=new JTextField("Hello World");
f.setEditable(false);
content.add(f);
```

Pierre

Answer (score 10):

Building on the answers:
You can use a JTextField without enabling the editing

```
JTextField f=new JTextField("Hello World");
f.setEditable(false);
f.setBackground(null); //this is the same as a JLabel
f.setBorder(null); //remove the border
```

I don't know how to stop the text from "Jumping" when you select it, or replace the text (programmatically). Maybe it is just my computer...

Comment: f.setCaretPosition(0) should avoid 'jumping' text on selection

Comment: @fredsmith `setCaretPosition(0)` did not prevent the "jump" in my testing. This did: `f.setMinimumSize(new Dimension((int) f.getPreferredSize().getWidth() + 1, (int) f.getPreferredSize().getHeight()));`

Comment: It doesn't seem like html is enabled for this implementation

Comment: @NoodleOfDeath, For html, call `setContentType("text/html")`

Answer (score 7):

When using JTextField, you will also want to remove the border:
`f.setBorder(null);`

and set the disabled text color: `f.setDisabledTextColor(Color.black);`

Answer (score 5):

As variant below CopyableLabel supports html tags and Fonts as JLabel.

```
public class CopyableLabel extends JTextPane {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1;

    private static final Font DEFAULT_FONT;

    static {
        Font font = UIManager.getFont("Label.font");
        DEFAULT_FONT = (font != null) ? font: new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 11);
    }

    public CopyableLabel() {
        construct();
    }

    private void construct() {
        setContentType("text/html");

        setEditable(false);
        setBackground(null);
        setBorder(null);

        putClientProperty(JEditorPane.HONOR_DISPLAY_PROPERTIES, true);
        setFont(DEFAULT_FONT);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

JLabels cannot be editable.

However, you could use a JTextField and just change the foreground / background colors to make it appear as a JLabel. If you wanted to be really fancy you could add code to change the colors when it's selected to indicate that it's editable.

Comment: what has editable to do with copying?

Comment: Selectable != Editable

Answer (score 0):

Besides the changes suggested in other responses *(setEditable, setContentType, setOpaque or setBackground, maybe setEnabled + setDisabledTextColor(Color.black), maybe setBorder(null) and/or setMargin(new Insets(0,0,0,0))*

To get the font of a JTextPane to look like a JLabel, see the suggestion from [this blog post](https://explodingpixels.wordpress.com/2008/10/28/make-jeditorpane-use-the-system-font/):

> "Unfortunately, simply calling set font on JEditorPane will have no effect, as the default font is pulled from a style sheet rather than the JComponent. There is, however, a clever way around the errant font default. The best way to change the default font in an HTML rendering JEditorPane, is to alter the style sheet like this:"

```
    // create a JEditorPane that renders HTML and defaults to the system font.
    JEditorPane editorPane = 
            new JEditorPane(new HTMLEditorKit().getContentType(),text);
    // set the text of the JEditorPane to the given text.
    editorPane.setText(text);

    // add a CSS rule to force body tags to use the default label font
    // instead of the value in javax.swing.text.html.default.csss
    Font font = UIManager.getFont("Label.font");
    String bodyRule = "body { font-family: " + font.getFamily() + "; " +
            "font-size: " + font.getSize() + "pt; }";
    ((HTMLDocument)editorPane.getDocument()).getStyleSheet().addRule(bodyRule);
```