# Make JTextPane background transparent

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

I have created my own Label class which has the advantage of being copyable.

```
public class CopyableLabel extends JTextPane {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -1;

private static final Font DEFAULT_FONT;

static 
{
    Font font = UIManager.getFont("Label.font");
    DEFAULT_FONT = (font != null) ? font: new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 11);
}

public CopyableLabel() {
    construct();
}

private void construct()
{
    setContentType("text/html");

    setEditable(false);
    setOpaque(false);
    setBackground(null);
    setBorder(null);

    putClientProperty(JEditorPane.HONOR_DISPLAY_PROPERTIES, true);
    setFont(DEFAULT_FONT);
}

public CopyableLabel(String text)
{
    super();
    construct();
    setText(text);
}

public void setFont(Font font)
{
    super.setFont(font);
    setMaximumSize(new Dimension(Short.MAX_VALUE,font.getSize()+4));
}

public CopyableLabel(String title, int align) 
{
    super();
    construct();
    setText(title);

    StyledDocument doc = getStyledDocument();
    SimpleAttributeSet center = new SimpleAttributeSet();
    StyleConstants.setAlignment(center, StyleConstants.ALIGN_CENTER);
    switch(align)
    {
        case JLabel.LEFT:
            StyleConstants.setAlignment(center, StyleConstants.ALIGN_LEFT);
            break;
        case JLabel.RIGHT:
            StyleConstants.setAlignment(center, StyleConstants.ALIGN_RIGHT);
            break;
    }
    doc.setParagraphAttributes(0, doc.getLength(), center, false);
}
```

The problem is, that with Nimbus Look and Feel the white background is looking ugly. So I look for a possibility to get the background transparent.

Do you have any solution?

Comment: You didn't create it, you got the code from this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/997942/selecting-text-from-a-jlabel

Comment: very helpful post

Answer (score 3):

Not shure if this helps. But using [Color](https://www.google.se/search?q=java%20Color&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=teAWWYu6NImWsAGF6L7IBQ) and especially Colors Constructor Color(r,g,b,a) where a is *alpha* which governs the transparency.

thus changing the construct() method to:

```
private void construct()
{
    setContentType("text/html");

    setEditable(false);
    setOpaque(true);
    backgroundColor = getBackground();
    int red = backgroundColor.getRed();
    int green = backgroundColor.getGreen();
    int blue = backgroundColor.getBlue();
    setBackground(new Color(red, green, blue, 25));
    //setBackground(null);
    setBorder(null);

    putClientProperty(JEditorPane.HONOR_DISPLAY_PROPERTIES, true);
    setFont(DEFAULT_FONT);
}
```

It worked for me when I tryed it and put your JTextPane modifyed with above mentioned code and put it on a translucent JFrame.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to set the HTML defaults themselves. I've never used Nimbus but I'm assuming maybe they are setting the background color for HTML rendering. You can set it manually somewhere in your app initialization after nimbus L&F stuff is set, at a global scope with the following:

```java
HTMLEditorKit kit = new HTMLEditorKit();
StyleSheet styleSheet = kit.getStyleSheet();
Style style = styleSheet.getStyle("body");
StyleConstants.setBackground(style, new Color(0,0,0,0));
```

This will make HTML render by default with a transparent background at a global scope. So for example if you're putting HTML into a JLabel or other Component you can then control background color with the normal setbackground without HTML backgrounds interfering.